# Inline C Varnish (VCL_deliver)

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am using Varnish 4.0.

My backend is adding to some responses an http header "x-count"

I would like to log the value of "x-count" into a file with a line break.

I assumed i should do it in VCL deliver.

Here is what i have so far :

```
sub vcl_deliver {

    if (resp.http.x-count-this:) {
        set resp.http.X-infodbg  = "xx";
        C{
           FILE *fp;
           fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w+");
           fputs(VRT_GetHdr(sp, HDR_OBJ, "\013x-count-this:"), fp);
           fputs("\n", fp);
           fclose(fp);
        }C
    }
}
```

Of course it doesnt work and there is a couple of errors ..

> ./vcl.gK2lu7uM.c: In function ‘VGC_function_vcl_deliver’:
>   ./vcl.gK2lu7uM.c:1049:22: error: ‘sp’ undeclared (first use in this
>   function) ./vcl.gK2lu7uM.c:1049:22: note: each undeclared identifier
>   is reported only once for each function it appears in
>   ./vcl.gK2lu7uM.c:1049:5: error: passing argument 2 of ‘VRT_GetHdr’
>   makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
>   ./vcl.gK2lu7uM.c:330:7: note: expected ‘const struct gethdr_s *’ but
>   argument is of type ‘int’ ./vcl.gK2lu7uM.c:1049:5: error: too many
>   arguments to function ‘VRT_GetHdr’ ./vcl.gK2lu7uM.c:330:7: note:
>   declared here

I have to say that i simply copy/pasted "sp" from some examples, but i have no idea where it comes from (i suppose the inline C was in a different context and therefore it was declared there but not in vcl_deliver)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the probably undocumented differences between Varnish 4 and 3 in the above examples are :

- VRT_GetHdr is now VRT_GetHdr(context, struct gethdr_s)
- sp doesn't exist, but there is a "ctx" variable

Found this, there :

http://jan.bogutzki.de/Artikel/395/set-ttl-in-varnish-4.html

```
   char *stuffid;
   const struct gethdr_s hdr = { HDR_BERESP, "\015x-count-this:" };
   stuffid = VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &hdr);
```

And now a different story: Varnish is crashing as soon as the backend sends back "count-this", but that is a different problem :p (my crappy C code probably)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Varnish 4.0 handy to test this out, but I was able to get your example working with Varnish 3.0. When I tried the VCL as is, I wasn't getting the exact error you are though. The first change:

```
if (resp.http.x-count-this:) {
```

needs to be:

```
if (resp.http.x-count-this) {
```

The colon should be left off of the header name when referred to this way. Next:

```
fputs(VRT_GetHdr(sp, HDR_OBJ, "\013x-count-this:"), fp);
```

needs to be:

```
fputs(VRT_GetHdr(sp, HDR_OBJ, "\015x-count-this:"), fp);
```

The length value in that string needs to be in octal for some reason, and `13` in octal is `15`. Making those changes got this to work for me. That being said, you many want to look into using `open` and `fcntl` instead of `fopen` since without file locking I'm not sure what the effect of multiple requests contending for that file would be.

Comment: Thank you but .. the ":" in the 'if' was an edit issue, but the "octal value instead of decimal" is definetely a good hint. however, "sp" variable still do not exist, probably a Varnish 3/4 thing :(